# Understanding keras.backend.max usage with tf.random_normal

Tags: tensorflow, keras

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

box_scores1 = tf.constant([[[ 9.188682,  11.484599 ],
                      [10.06533,    7.557296 ]],

                    [[10.099248,  10.591225 ],
                     [10.592823 ,  7.8770704]]])

box_scores2 = tf.random_normal([2,2,2], mean=10, stddev=1, dtype=tf.float32, seed = 1)

box_class_scores1 = K.max(box_scores1, axis=-1)
box_class_scores2 = K.max(box_scores2, axis=-1)

print(box_scores1.eval())
print(box_scores2.eval())

print(box_class_scores1.eval())
print(box_class_scores2.eval())
```

Output:

```
[[[ 9.188682  11.484599 ]
  [10.06533    7.557296 ]]

 [[10.099248  10.591225 ]
  [10.592823   7.8770704]]]
[[[ 9.188682  11.484599 ]
  [10.06533    7.557296 ]]

 [[10.099248  10.591225 ]
  [10.592823   7.8770704]]]
[[11.484599 10.06533 ]
  [10.591225 10.592823]]
[[10.242094 10.515779]
 [12.083789 11.397354]]
```

As, we can see values in box_scores1 and box_scores2 are same but the result obtained after applying max operation differs. How can the values of box_class_scores1 and box_class_scores2 be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with the `max` function, but a misunderstanding with tensorflow, as most of its operations are symbolic, so when you use `tf.random_mormal`, this does not produce random numbers, but a symbolic normal distribution with the given mean and standard distribution.

Then, each time you evaluate this distribution, **it generates different outputs**, so your first eval looks ok, but the second produces a different output that is given to `max`, so it produces a different output than just giving a constant vector.

Comment: I still don't get it, though box_scores2 is random but when printed the values in both box_scores1 and box_scores2 are same. So, the output of K.max should be same? Please elaborate if I'm missing something. Thanks

Comment: @quintin Random numbers are generated each time you call .eval() on the normal distribution, you can check this by running print(box_scores2.eval()) multiple times.

Comment: Now i get it. Thanks